# Why does my Samsung Galaxy S6 show more used space?

Tags: storage, samsung-galaxy-s-6

Recently, I noticed that all my music(copied from my computer) disappeared from my phone. Since I wasn't really listening to it, I figured that I might have accidentally deleted it when I was cleaning some files. However, my phone still shows as much used space as before deleting it. I looked at everything in my phone using my computer and I noticed something very weird: while it says that it has a bit over 23GB of data, all the files in it (including hidden files) amount to 4.69GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since no one was able to say anything I guess I should answer this for someone as clumsy as me.

Apparently, I installed an app and that app "removed" everything. Its removal process is apparently moving the files to a folder called ".removed". Everything was in that folder.

Fixed.